# how to get bazel cache items or fail

Tags: bazel

I know this is stupid, but I am trying to prove that bazel will do great things for us. We have a hairy, complex build system and it is going to be a huge lift to move it to bazel. I have been told we can't have the money/time to do this. So I trying to do this bass ackward.
I want to make rules for our unit tests that don't use bazel for the build. My thinking is that when I run a test, it first looks for a marker file with the current hash tree. If it's not there, I run the test and gather stats about the time it took. Then I put that info in the marker file with a bazel rule. The next time for the same hash tree, I find the marker file, extract the info and generate a nice message that bazel just saved X time on this job. I can then scrape those messages and produce shiny management graphs demonstrating how great having hash dependency test control is. Hopefully, this will get us funded to do it right.
I am hoping you stop laughing at me long enough to help figure this out.
thanks,
jerry

Answer (score 0):

Bazel do not write anything to source directory, and it is hard to do this. Your solution is probably doable, but you need to know how bazel works underhood, and it will be overkill for such a hack

IMO the best way is to write a simple bash script, which will run you tests:

```py
sh_test(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["test_wrapper.sh"],
    data = [all_files_required_by_tests_runner],
)
```

and you will get that pretty message about saved time for free